# get total count of each type in a column

Tags: mysql

I am doing a jasper report to count the statistic of the fruits choices.

I have 2 table, Fruit, Fruit_choices

Table **Fruit** :

| id | fruit |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | apple |
| 1 | banana |
| 2 | orange |

Table **Fruit_choices** ：

| id | choice_1 | choice_2 | choice_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 1 |

I want to know the sum of the user that select the fruits in choice_1,choice_2,choice_3

My ideal output is like below

| fruit | c1Count | c2Count | c3Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| banana | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| orange | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: It helps to include what you've tried in terms of a SQL statement. It's also worth noting that this data isn't organized in a way that's very relational, which significantly complicates querying it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only 3 choice, you can get the result with combination of UNION and Aggregation.

If your number of choices increase, then the query would be more complicated and expensive

```
SELECT f.FRUIT,SUM(C1COUNT),SUM(C2COUNT),SUM(C3COUNT)
FROM 
    FRUIT f 
JOIN
    (
    SELECT  CHOICE_1 AS FRUIT ,COUNT(1) AS C1COUNT, 0 AS C2COUNT, 0 AS C3COUNT
    FROM FRUIT_CHOICES 
    GROUP BY CHOICE_1
    UNION
    
    SELECT  CHOICE_2 AS FRUIT,0 AS C1COUNT, COUNT(1) AS C2COUNT, 0 AS C3COUNT
    FROM FRUIT_CHOICES
    GROUP BY CHOICE_2
    UNION
    
    SELECT  CHOICE_3 AS FRUIT,0 AS C1COUNT, 0 AS C2COUNT, COUNT(1) AS C3COUNT
    FROM FRUIT_CHOICES
    GROUP BY CHOICE_3
    ) c 
ON f.ID=c.FRUIT
GROUP BY c.FRUIT
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=07dd3ca27d231cfcdfbcbefff7f140f6

Explanation:

We can separate our data for each choice. For example, for CHOICE_1, we can group by it and get count of only CHOICE_1. We have to hardcode `0` for other counts.

```
SELECT  CHOICE_1 AS FRUIT ,COUNT(1) AS C1COUNT, 0 AS C2COUNT, 0 AS C3COUNT
FROM FRUIT_CHOICES 
GROUP BY CHOICE_1
```

This will give you below result.

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| FRUIT | C1COUNT | C2COUNT | C3COUNT |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| F0    |       2 |       0 |       0 |
| F2    |       1 |       0 |       0 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Similarly union for other 2 choices to get below result

```
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| FRUIT | C1COUNT | C2COUNT | C3COUNT |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
| F0    |       2 |       0 |       0 |
| F2    |       1 |       0 |       0 |
| F0    |       0 |       1 |       0 |
| F1    |       0 |       1 |       0 |
| F2    |       0 |       1 |       0 |
| F1    |       0 |       0 |       1 |
| F2    |       0 |       0 |       1 |
+-------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Now you can group by FRUIT and use `SUM` to get count of each `FRUIT`. Then join the final result with `FRUIT` table to get name of the FRUIT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using conditional aggregation. No `GROUP BY` clause is required in this case. If you're interested, try it.

```
select fruit,c1Count,c2Count,c3Count
from Fruit t1 
join
    (select 0 as id,
    sum(case choice_1 when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as c1Count,
    sum(case choice_2 when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as c2Count,
    sum(case choice_3 when 0 then 1 else 0 end) as c3Count
    from Fruit_choices
    union
    select 1 ,
    sum(case choice_1 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) ,
    sum(case choice_2 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) ,
    sum(case choice_3 when 1 then 1 else 0 end)  
    from Fruit_choices
    union
    select 2 ,
    sum(case choice_1 when 2 then 1 else 0 end) ,
    sum(case choice_2 when 2 then 1 else 0 end) ,
    sum(case choice_3 when 2 then 1 else 0 end) 
    from Fruit_choices
    ) t2
using(id)
;
```